# Calculate Speed and Altitude in Android without using built in methods

Tags: android, performance, geolocation, location, altitude

I am trying find out the speed and altitude in android without using `getspeed()` and `getAltitude()` methods. If any one has any reference material or code snippet with respect to this,please share it so that it can be of some help to me.

Comment: "without using getspeed() and getAltitude() methods"  - why?

Answer (score 1):

Speed can be done by keeping track of location on subsequent updates, finding the distance between them, and dividing by the time difference.  Altitude-  good luck, you'd need signal strength info that I don't think you can get.  You really don't want to do it.

Comment: Thats true.. I am using Great-Circle method to calculate the distance, but I am not getting the correct interval of time to calculate the speed. What must be the deominator. ? We will get distance = CustomeSpeed(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2) bbut what about the denominator?how to get the time at (lat1,lon1) and (lat2,lon2)

Comment: Got speed..But how to find the altitude?

Comment: altitude is identical in this sense to lat and lon (although less accurate)  If you really want it from a non gps based source some phones with pressure sensors give you an alternative although you need calibration.